# Qual a diferença entre "feliz de quem" e "feliz quem"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões

Já vi essas duas grafias para expressar mais ou menos o mesmo sentido:

"feliz de quem caminha com Deus"

"feliz quem tem muitos amigos"

Alguém sabe o porquê dessa regência estranha da palavra "feliz"?

Comment: Sabe o significado dessas expressões? Talvez "feliz de quem caminha com Deus" seja "é feliz daqueles que caminha com Deus" ou "feliz por ser quem caminha com Deus"?

Comment: Ficar feliz **de alguem** comparado com: feliz quem ou aquele que, ou seja aquela pessoa. Nemhum um dos dois tem algo estranho.